# Integral $\int_{\sigma}{{e^zdz}\over{z-2}}$ with $\sigma:[0,2\pi] \to C, \sigma (t)=4e^{it}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, curves

How should I tackle this integral? I can't use the fact that $\sigma$ is a closed curve because the function is not defined in z=2 which is inside the curve. Any tip on how to proceed is welcomed.

Comment: This is the whole concept of the *residue theorem*, isn't it? (But please correct $\sigma(t)$ in the title.)

Comment: @CristianDesivo do you know the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: @kobe I didn't, thanks, I think thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cauchy's integral theorem $e^2= {1\over{2\pi i}}\int_{\sigma}{e^zdz\over{z-2}} $

Then $\int_{\sigma}{e^zdz\over{z-2}}=e^22\pi i $